# How to display with a vba script a gif when the value of a cell changes, and then hide it

Tags: excel, vba, image, gif, animated-gif

I have a spreadsheet with a table where the cells of the column "F" can assume different values: I need to show a gif only when the value is equal to "DONE".
After that event, by clicking on the gif, I would like to hide it, in order to proceede to update the value of the other rows in the columns F and, if the value of another cell is equal to "DONE", repeat the display of the gif. 
I assembled a code by searching on the net, but it's not complete and it doesn't work as I would like (I don't have enough expertise).
I don't know neither if in my worksheet I have to insert the gif with the "insert-pictures" option or as an "object".
Here below the starting code, added to another piece of macro I've already used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dgr As String
Dim n, i, ntab As Integer
Dim myImage As Shape
Dim imageWidth As Double


ntab = Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For itab = 3 To ntab + 1
' Aim: show a animated gif when the content of a cell in the column "F" changes to "DONE"
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F" & itab)) Is Nothing Then
            Dim Sh As Shape
            For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                Sh.Top = 60
                Sh.Left = 189
                Sh.Visible = msoFalse
            Next
            dgr = Range("F" & itab).Value
            If dgr = DONE Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True
            End If
        End If
' Script to update the today-date automatically if cell values in the columns E, F, G change
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E" & itab)) Is Nothing Then
        szTod = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY")
        Range("H" & itab) = szTod
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F" & itab)) Is Nothing Then
        szTod = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY")
        Range("H" & itab) = szTod
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G" & itab)) Is Nothing Then
        szTod = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY")
        Range("H" & itab) = szTod
        End If
Next itab
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI if you want an animated GIF it's not as simple as using a regular image.

Comment: @TimWilliams ok...actually I don't know how to use a regular image either..anyway difficult is not impossible: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Every time this triggers it would display the image for each DONE cell - seems like you need some way to determine if you already showed the image for any given row, and then not show it again.  What is the `For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes` loop doing?  do you have multiple shapes on the sheet?  BTW it would be safer to use `Me` as the sheet reference.

Comment: Maybe using [Userform and additional control is an option](http://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=26667)?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't have multiple shapes on the sheet, just one gif that I would display when the value in the column F changes to DONE

Comment: So it just displays next to the "DONE" ?  Then what?  The user clicks it and it disappears?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, my purpose is to display the gif only if the content of the cell changes to "DONE", and then hiding the gif when the user clicks it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Columns("F"), Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.Row >= 3 And rng.Value = "DONE" Then
            With Me.Shapes("Picture 1")
                .Visible = True
                .Left = rng.Offset(0, 1).Left
                .Top = rng.Offset(0, 1).Top
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub

'assign this macro to the shape
Sub HideMe()
    Me.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a very appreciated gift for the gif :)  I've modified it by using the "Object" shape instead of "Picture" shape, because otherwise I wasn't able to show the gif.

Comment: Here below the modified code, feel free to adjust/improve it

Comment: If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Columns("F"), Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.Row >= 3 And rng.Value = "DONE" Then
            With Me.Shapes("Object 1")
                '.Visible = True
                '.Left = rng.Offset(0, 1).Left
                '.Top = rng.Offset(0, 1).Top
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 1")).Select
                Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
            End With
        End If
    End If